# Add Image Marker and animate it like a radar (rotation)

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I want  to rotate a marker as a radar animation like this picture

[image]

```
 LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Showing the current location in Google Map
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
```

Can anyone helop me to slove this problem 
 `

Comment: is it not working ? or there is an exception ?

Comment: i like to know  how to set an imageview as a marker and and to apply an animatoion to this imageview

Comment: please check my answer and give me feedback on the result

Comment: you want to add an imageview as a marker ?

Comment: yes and animate it like a radar animation

Comment: please check the add marker to the map answer

Answer (score 1):

this is how you add an imageView marker on map like the following :

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);



  // create marker
 MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng ).title("marker");  
 // Changing marker icon
 marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.image_marker)));   
// adding marker
 googleMap.addMarker(marker);
```

and for the animation try something like the following as a start :

```
final long duration = 400;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();


final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
        float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration);
       marker.setRotation(marker.getRotation()+2);
        if (t < 1.0) {
            // Post again 10ms later.
            handler.postDelayed(this, 10);
        } else {
            // animation ended
        }
    }
});
```

Hope that Helps .

Comment: I want to set a rotate animation to the marker not to the camera thank's

Comment: i succeeded in to set marker from drawable and this is a screen shot
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/K9aHk.png
now can any one help me to set the animation into the marker to appear as  radar

Comment: yes :) can you help me how to animate it 
 `  Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim);` this is the animation 
but i can't set .staranimation to the marker

Answer (score 0):

`Marker` has [`setRotation(float)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#setRotation%28float%29), but I am unsure how you will manipulate that.